# Linear regression in a loglog-plot with fixed slope

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, pgfplotstable

Goal: create a plot to compare the empirical convergence rate of a numerical method with the one expected from the theory.

Accordingly, given a loglog-plot, I would like to add the line which has a prescribed slope (in this case, the convergence of the method) and the best intercept to fit the data (e.g., in a least-square sense).

Question: how to do a linear regression with fixed slope in pgfplots?

What I have done so far is the following:
(1) compute the regression line (of the logarithm of the quantities),
(2) save the intercept,
(3) plot the line with the slope expected from the theory and this intercept.

This is a good approximation of what I am looking for, provided the data are in agreement with the theory.

Thanks

MdFB

Comment: Can you include what you have? Also you can keep the log values of points and create a linear regression column in the table with `pgfplotstable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gnuplot` to do the parameter estimation within PGFPlots.

To estimate both the slope and the intercept, you could use the following `\addplot` command:

```
  \addplot [red, raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
   a = -1;
   b = 0.1;
   f(x) = a*x+b;
   fit f(x) 'data.dat' using (log($1)):(log($2)) via a,b;
   set samples 2;
   plot [x=100:10000] exp(f(log(x)));  
  };
```

This defines the initial parameter values and the equation, and then fits the parameters to the log transformed values found in the data file `data.dat`. For generating the plot, the number of samples is set to 2 (since we're plotting a straight line), the exponentiation function has to be applied to the function value, and the logarithm has to be taken of the x samples.

To prescribe the slope, change the `via a,b` in the `fit` line to `via b`. That way, `a` will be kept fixed at its initial value, and only the intercept will be estimated.

Here's an example looking at the convergence of the [Monte Carlo approach to estimating Pi (Example 1)](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/MonteCarloPiMod.html). The red line uses a theoretical convergence rate of -1, the black line uses the rate estimated from the data.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
N   e
100 0.0984
400 0.0316
1600 0.0284
6400     0.00659
10000 0.00359
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmode=log, ymode=log,
    domain=100:10000
  ]
  \addplot [only marks] table [y=e] {data.dat};
  \addplot [red, raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
   a = -1;
   b = 0.1;
   f(x) = a*x+b;
   fit f(x) 'data.dat' using (log($1)):(log($2)) via b;
   set samples 2;
   plot [x=100:10000] exp(f(log(x)));  
  } node [pos=0.25, above right] {$a=-1$};

  \addplot [raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
   a = -1;
   b = 0.1;
   f(x) = a*x+b;
   fit f(x) 'data.dat' using (log($1)):(log($2)) via a,b;
   set samples 2;
   plot [x=100:10000] exp(f(log(x)));  
  } node [pos=0.25, below left] {$a=-0.67$} ;


  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```