# Adding reference lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I constantly need to add reference lines to my PGF plots which should match the data. I am looking for ways to implement a command that does this automatically and I am hoping someone can give me some pointers on the best way to do this.

The following MWE with the comments hopefully illustrate the point:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{line12.dat}
  x y
  1 48.43734545112396
  2 89.8468830844395
  4 210.67967341436497
  7 475.619178754322
  8 603.599030569327
  9 821.1933877936549
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmode=log,ymode=log,xmin=1, xmax=10,domain=1:10]
    % This is the line plot
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,mark=o,draw=black] table[x=x, y=y] {line12.dat};
    \label{myline}

    \addplot[dashed] {x^2};  % This is the reference line which does not match the data

    % To make the reference line f(x) align with the data,
    % I have to multiply by a constant: mean(y_i / x_i**2)
    \addplot[dashed] {18.89041408136126 * x^2};  % This is the reference line

    % I want to implement a command that does this automatically like this
    % \addref[dashed, x=x, y=y] {line12.data}{x**2};

    % Or even just referencing the line if that is somehow possible
    % \addref[dashed, data=myline] {x**2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Once I know how to implement this, I am hoping to introduce some logic to remove outliers as well or use other functions to find the constant (like the median).

Comment: Not quite the same, but here is an example for how one can calculate an R-squared value from a table: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407694/  A similar approach could be used to calculate the 18.89.. value. Whether it's the best approach I can't say though.

Comment: I had in mind that there was a similar question about a year ago here on TeX.SX, but I couldn't find it. But I could find the corresponding issue on the PGFPlots tracker: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/352. Maybe this helps.

Comment: If using [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) as calculation engine is an option for you, please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174928/95441, too.